# Convert Standard Item to Matrix Child Item

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a scenario I'm a little stumped with, and hoping the Stack gurus can assist.

I have product ABC123.WHT (example) as a standard inventory item, with over 12 months of history/transactions etc... ABC123.WHT is a white product, and ABC123.BLK is of course black.

They were originally created as standard (non-matrix) items during implementation, but for various reasons I now want to have them as matrix items, ABC123 naturally as the parent, and ABC123.BLK & ABC123.WHT as the child items.

Now when looking at the item record information in the F12-Console, there are a number of fields my script has changed:

```
hasparent = 'T'                                // changed from 'F' to 'T'
parent = '1234'                                // internal id of the parent code
itemoptions = ['CUSTCOL_COLOUR']               // set the option array with the colour list id
matrixoptioncustitem_colour = '100'            // colour list id for WHITE
matrixoptioncustitem_colour_display = 'White'  // colour name
matrixtype = 'CHILD'
```

My script can successfully change these fields, and *sort of* links the new child to the parent (ie. in lists shows as `ABC123 : ABC123.BLK`) however, the child code *does not* show up in the parent code item record in the Matrix Items list.

In the `child` item, the `subitem of` field *is* populated, but not `read-only` like a true child item, and thus could be deleted by any user with item-edit permissions.

Additionally, *true* child items show the MATRIX-SUBITEM subheading next to the item name when displaying the item record, whereas the *child*ed standard item does not. It also does *not* show the item options (such as colour) in the child record.

This process *does* work when moving a *true* child item from one parent to another, so I suspect there is perhaps a kind of hidden flag I need to set to truely activate the child-parent link.

To me this would be a far simpler and safer method for my scenario, rather than merging all the transactional history from one item id to another.

Anyone with the answer to this one?

Comment: can you please add some more details into this ? what do you mean by `the child code does not show up in the parent code item record in the Matrix Items list` ? I had implemented some sort of scenario like this before but those I had to create dynamically through an external system.

Comment: On the item parent record, the child items are shown in a sublist. I will get some screenshots to show the screens

Comment: Aha, I may have just found it. As soon as I mentioned sublist above, I thought perhaps I need to push the item into the parent record sublist 'matrixmach'... will test later tonight

Comment: Hi @SteveReeder do you have a sample script you used to move child items from one parent to another?  From what I gathered from SuiteAnswers it's not something you can do using CSV export/import so scripting might be the only viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to shift a child record from one parent to another, was by changing the `parent` field in the child record from the original parent itemid to the alternative parent item id.

To do this, the new parent code must be set up with the same `itemoptions` data as the old parent, or the link won't be created.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Steve, moving child items to a new parent works well.  I just created a Mass Update script with the New Parent as a parameter.  Did you manage to work out how to move a simple item to become a parent of a matrix item?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue as you, there is no way to do this via Netsuite UI, and therefore it's not going to work well via suitescript as well.
As an alternative, you can create a custom record, for example "Custom Matrix Children" and add into Item record.
This custom record will store all the children records